# Solve equation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

suppose I have some equation of this form $A(z)=B(z)$. Is valid to just solve for $\log(A(z))=\log(B(z))$ or $\exp(A(z))=\exp(B(z))$ without caring what exactly $A$ and $B$ are or the domain of $z$? By valid, I mean not losing or acquiring more solutions.

Comment: Do you have a specific application in mind? If so, you might need to reword to circumvent the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

$$\exp(w+i2\pi)=\exp(w),$$ so taking the exponential introduces extra solutions.

And taking the logarithm doesn't work for zero arguments.

Comment: Are there any rules to follow or conditions to check when solving these equations using log and exp? I saw sometimes the textbook just takes log on both sides and solve e.g. $z^{1+i}=4$ without any justification.